# Help converting .py to .exe, using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

The script I ran

```
# p2e_simple_con.py
# very simple script to make an executable file with py2exe
# put this script and your code script into the same folder
# run p2e_simple_con.py
# it will create a subfolder 'dist' where your exe file is in
# has the same name as the script_file with extension exe
# (the other subfolder 'build' can be deleted)
# note: with console code put a wait line at the end

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

sys.argv.append("py2exe")
sys.argv.append("-q")

# this is your code script file, change it as needed
# use it in the working directory or give full path
script_file = 'DateTime_Test1.py'

# create a single .exe file and use compression
# (the .exe file is 30% larger with no compression)
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': 1,}},
    zipfile = None,
    # replace console with windows for a GUI program
    console = [{'script': script_file}]
)
```

I tried this but got the following error

```
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'console'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zipfile'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: py2exe.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: py2exe.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: py2exe.py --help-commands
   or: py2exe.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'py2exe'
```

Comment: have you gone through this tutorial...http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial?highlight=((Tutorial))

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
sys.argv.append("py2exe")
sys.argv.append("-q")
```

seem "unusual" and likely to be causing that "invalid command" message. I'd be curious to know the rationale for having them.

**Update**

A common convention is to name the script `setup.py` (although in this case it's named `p2e_simple_con.py` it seems). The `setup` function in it parses the command line, and usually you expect to run it with a command such as:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

where `py2exe` is a command that the py2exe package understands and then builds the EXE file. So as long as the py2exe package is installed, that command should be accepted.

The line `sys.argv.append("py2exe")` adds that command to the command-line, so in your case you should just be able to type:

```
python p2e_simple_con.py
```

to build the exe. However, if you haven't installed the py2exe package, then the base `distutils` wouldn't recognise the `py2exe` command. But in that case, I'd expect you to get an exception for the line `import py2exe`. So, I'm not sure what's going on.

What is the command you used to run the setup program?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea (not really an answer but I can't comment).

Since it seems from the error message that there is a parameter given to `py2exe` that it doesn't accept, I'd guess it's the `-q` parameter. So try removing the line `sys.argv.append("-q")` and run the scrip then.

I haven't used py2exe myself so I can't really test this. It's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `py2exe` is for python 3,

the one for python 2 seems to be `py2exe2msi`

I'm also getting a similar error in python 2, trying to do code that was written for python 3 version.

Answer (score -1):

The two warnings are due to an errant comma inside the options dictionary, after the final value. You want to have

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    # replace console with windows for a GUI program
    console = [{'script': script_file}]
)
```

Try and see if that fixes your error.