# Py2Exe: "error: invalid command: py2exe"

Tags: python, cmd, py2exe

I can't figure out how to use py2exe, what am I doing wrong?

This is my my setup.py file witch is in the same folder as the rest of my project:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'])
```

And then, as described on the [homepage](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) of py2exe, I navigate to the project directory with my python-files and type

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

But I only get this error!

```
E:\Programme(x86)\Python2.7x86\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'console'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'py2exe'
```

I've seen and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380612/help-converting-py-to-exe-using-py2exe) post and lot's of others, but all seem to solve the problem by:

- installing py2exe
- navigating to the source path
- typing in the correct command
- correcting setup.py

All this (seems to me) is correct in my case. Maybe the solution is written in the error, but I can't interpret it usefully...

Other things I tried:

- Use absolute paths
- python setup.py py2exe [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871520/invalid-command-py2exe)

I recognized that the problem occurs while importing py2exe, python doesn't execute anything after the second line.

**Note:** The PATH variable is correctly set, typing "python" and then "import py2exe" into the cmd works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: It very much looks like the py2exe module isn't available to the python interpreter that you're launching.  Do you have more than one version of python installed?  I can reproduce the error message you receive by commenting the `import py2exe` line in one of my setup scripts.

Comment: No, I don't think so...
I've tried to start both the shell and the script with the absolute path, and I may import py2exe on the shell, the error above stays.

Comment: It's so weird! The function `help("modules py2exe")`, witch searches for  modules with similar names like "py2exe", finds py2exe in the shell but returns None if executed in a file! Python.exe is the same, I've checked that  with `sys.executable`.

It's not the first time I installed an external library, all others worked.

Comment: That sounds to me like something is broken in either your python install, or your py2exe install.  I'd half-consider scrapping that python interpreter, or maybe even just installing a separate copy of python to another directory somewhere, installing py2exe there, and testing with a separate interpreter.  Maybe something in `site.py` is screwy?  Where did you get your python install from?

Comment: Also, what are the names of some of your python modules?  Did you name any of them `py2exe` or the like?  Perhaps you're creating confusion for the interpreter because of something it's finding in your path that it shouldn't and preventing the actual py2exe module from being loaded?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it. I re-installed python, also I found a compiled python-file "py2exe.pyc" lying in the same folder... For whatever reason the windows-search-function did not find it.... Maybe it did not exist when I searched, and the problem had a different origin at this point in time, so, bad luck? Or maybe was just too stupid myself. Anyway, thanks a lot for you time! It works now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `g.d.d.c` I found the problem.

There was a "py2exe.pyc" in the same directory witch confused the python-interpreter.
Besides I did not know there was a file with this name, I also didn't know you can import and use them like modules...

If your problem stays,  test if it works after re-installing Python.